# If $\sum (a_j)^2$ abs converge , does $\sum a_j / (j+1) $ that too?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Suppose that $\sum (a_j)^2$ converge absolute, how can I prove that $\sum a_j / (j+1)$ does that too? I don't exactly know where to start to prove this. Can somebody help me or give a hint?

Comment: Below you find a hint. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I was now trying to work on it, it is a very difficult question. Is it right that you need to use the comparison test after it?

Comment: Comparison test could be useful.

Comment: But I don't know what to do with the hint. How can I use that? Maybe I need one extra step

Comment: Is $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(j+1)^2}$ a convergent series?

Comment: Yes, it is a convergent serie

Comment: So what may we conclude about the non negative series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{|a_j|}{j+1}$?

Comment: That converges too?

Comment: Yes,  a non negative series is divergent to $+\infty$ or convergent. The inequality says that the partial sums are bounded by the square-root of the product of the sums of the two convergent series on the right.

Comment: And is it maybe an idea to complete that by editing your hint to a complete "story" so I can put it all together? Or is that too much to ask? I would like to understand it and I am not able to understand it right now. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, now (or later) you should be able to put all the pieces together and to complete the proof. This is the only way to understand this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that by [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), for any positive integer $n$,
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{|a_j|}{j+1}\right)^2\leq 
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(j+1)^2}.$$